# How do i know that i am using Recurring payment or subscription

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am confuse with the recurring payments and the subscription,what is the difference between the two the recurring payment and subscription.how do i know that i am using recurring payments.please enlighten my mind.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions are created through custom created Payments Standard buttons. Recurring Payments are created through CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API calls.

Subscription ID's start with "S-" and Recurring Profile ID's start with "I-".

Comment: HI PayPal_Patrick, what does CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API calls?does it means it uses the PDT or the IPN,if we use this PDT or IPN so i am in recurring payments?..when i looked at in my sandbox.paypal business account in the history tab i can see all customer and with the "TYPE" -> Recurring Payment From, about the subscription standard button i created the button in the sandbox.paypal and then i generate the code that's how i know in subscription.

Comment: I don't understand the question "what does CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API calls?" The CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API call is something your site sends to PayPal defining a set of parameters for billing the buyer. It isn't related to IPN or PDT. Check the Recurring Profile / Subscription ID to find out what kind you're creating. Custom created Subscription buttons create "S-" ID's and Subscription buttons saved in your account create an "I-" profile.

Comment: Also, StackOverflow is not the place to ask these kind of questions. This is a place to get assistance with programming issues. With questions about the kind of product you're using and clarification you'll want to reach out to PayPal.

Comment: Hi  PayPal_Patrick ,This is the profile of active subscription details.. Profile start date Jul 19, 2013 | Profile ID I-L0RR1R4A4FNC

Comment: "CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API call is something your site sends to PayPal defining a set of parameters "..my subscription button has dropped down with amount.this is what you mean recurring ?